# Softlayer API to activate storage failover

Tags: api, storage, failover, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to activate the failover  of the storage via Softlayer API.
I wrote this code

```
import SoftLayer
API_USERNAME = 'xxx'
API_KEY = 'yyy'
iscsiId_primary = AAAA
iscsiId_replica = BBBB
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
networkStorageService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage']

networkStorageService.FailoverToReplicant(id=iscsiId_primary)
```

The console returned me this error

> *SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue): Invalid value provided for 'The replicant id provided is not part of the replication
>   partners associated to this volume.'.*

If I try to put the replica storage ID the error is

> *SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Replication is not supported by this storage type.*

I think that the call to the failover function is incorrect. Someone could send me the correct syntax?.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SoftLayer_Network_Storage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/failoverToReplicant) method, it is neccesary specify "replicantId" parameter.

Try the following in your code:

```
networkStorageService.FailoverToReplicant(iscsiId_replica, id=iscsiId_primary)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much.